# Finding the set of points

Tags: geometry

Let us have a plane, and in it given dots $A$ and $B$, and a given distance $d$. Determine the place of all points $X$ in that plane such that we have $XA^2-XB^2=d^2$. I know that this is elementary, but have no clue. Thanks for your answers.

Comment: How you define a point multiplied by a point? The order of the left side is 3, and the right side is 2 - are you sure you defined well the challenge?

Comment: @Moti $XA^2$ means the square of the length of $XA$.

Answer (score 0):

Let point $A=(A_x,A_y)$, point $B=(B_x,B_y)$, and point $X=(x,y)$. Then
$$XA^2=(A_x-x)^2+(A_y-y)^2\\XB^2=(B_x-x)^2+(B_y-y)^2$$
Substituting into $XA^2-XB^2=d^2$ gives
$$(A_x-x)^2+(A_y-y)^2-(B_x-x)^2-(B_y-y)^2=d^2$$
Solving for $y$ gives us a linear equation
$$y=\frac{x(2A_x-2B_x)+B_x^2+B_y^2-A_x^2-A_y^2 +d^2}{(2B_y-2A_y)}$$

Comment: The answer looks great. I tried to find any unique quality of the line with GeoGebra and could not realize anything extraordinary of the line. Good response.

Answer (score 0):

Let $C$ be a point on the line $p$ which contains $A$ and $B$, such that it holds $CA^2-CB^2=d^2$. Now, let $q$ be a line perpendicular to $p$, which contains C. Let's prove $q$ is a solution. Let $D$ be some other point ($C$ is clearly a solution) in that line. Now consider triangles with right angles $\triangle CAD$ and $\triangle DBC$ and $DB^2=BC^2+DC^2$ and $DA^2=AC^2+CD^2$ meaning that $DA^2-DB^2=CA^2-CB^2=d^2$ and the last equation we have proved. Thanks to you all, especially to guy who I have downvoted(now erased the post) slight modification of his solution is a solution.

Comment: This only proves that the solution is a line perpendicular to the line containing $A$ and $B$.